# Surjectivity of an integration map

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, integration, differential-geometry

*N.B.*: Thanks to studiosus answer I realised I should ask for more conditions or otherwise the answer is straightforwardly wrong. I rechecked my problem and added new assumptions that I boldface.

Given $\tau>0$ we have a finite number of smooth maps $$\gamma_i:[0,\tau]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n,\ i=1,\ldots,s.$$ Let $V$ the real vector space spanned by $\gamma_1,\ldots,\gamma_s$. To every $\gamma\in V$ we associate $n$ smooth **non-negative** functions $$f_\gamma^1,\ldots,f_\gamma^n:[0,\tau]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$$ **such that $f_\gamma^j(0)=f_\gamma^j(\tau)=0$**. I would like to prove that
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
V & \longrightarrow &\mathbb{R}^n\\
\gamma & \longmapsto & \left(\int_0^\tau f^1_\gamma(t)dt\cdots\int_0^\tau f^n_\gamma(t)dt\right)
\end{array}
$$
is surjective assuming the following hypothesis:

1) There exists $t_0\in(0,\tau)$ such that $(f_{\gamma_1}^1(t_0)\cdots f_{\gamma_1}^n(t_0)),\ldots,(f_{\gamma_s}^1(t_0)\cdots f_{\gamma_s}^n(t_0))$ span $\mathbb{R}^n$.

2) The mappings 
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
V & \longrightarrow & C^\infty([0,\tau],\mathbb{R})\\ 
\gamma &\longmapsto & f_\gamma^j
\end{array}
$$
are linear for $j=1,\ldots,n$.

N.B.: The question actually comes from a differential geometry problem (hence the tag) but I tried to get rid of all the unnecessary stuff and keep the essential information. Hopefully that will suffice to get your hints.

Answer (score 6):

This is already false for $n=1, s=1$. Take $\gamma=\gamma_1$, the identity map $[0, 2\pi]\to {\mathbb R}$, $f_\gamma(t)=\sin(t)$, and extend this map to the rest of $V$ by linearity.

Edit: Your updated question is not much different from the original one and, unsurprisingly, has the same (negative) answer. For instance, take $n=2$, the paths $\gamma_k, k=1, 2,$ are the horizontal segments $[0, 2\pi k]\times \{0\}\subset R^2$ with affine parameterization; as for the functions, use, say: 
$$f_{\gamma_1}(t)=(2t + \sin(t), 2t),$$ 
$$f_{\gamma_2}(t)=(2t, 2t+ \sin(2t)).$$

One last thing: Maybe you should ask the differential geometry question you are actually interested in (I assume, it is something about Jacobi fields).  However, please, make it a separate question from this one, otherwise it will be a bit ridiculous.

Comment: Uncannily, I was typing up _precisely_ the same counterexample.... :)

Comment: @user86418: My guess is that hundreds of other users might have thought of this function since it requires no computation.

Comment: Oh, you are totally right. Thanks to your comment I realised that I should require more conditions. I'll recheck the differential geometry problem, but I'm quite sure I can assume that the functions $f_{\gamma}^j$ do not change signs in $[0,\tau]$. I'll change the question accordingly.

Comment: @A.Bellmunt: What you want is still false even with the extra assumptions. Do you want to change your question one more time?

Comment: If the $f_\gamma$ are non-negative you certainly wouldn't get any vectors with negative coefficients on the image side..

Comment: I see your points. I'm missing something for sure. I'll review it all again. Thanks for your help anyway.